# Listen to all html video events

Tags: events, html, video, listener

Playing around with html5 video and was wondering if there was a way to list its events as it happens.

I have one for ended - *myVideo.addEventListener('ended',videoEnded,false);*

Which works fine but how can i create a a listener which will listen to every event and name them?

```
myVideo.addEventListener('ALL',AddToLog,false);
function AddToLog(){
   console.log(eventname);
}
```

Any pointers welcome.

Dan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You need to listen to specific events.

You can find a list of possibly available events from [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#mediaevents)

Comment: thanks jani! Don't suppose you know if theres a listener that will work for when the 'next' (>>|) button is pressed (in fullscreen mode) as 'ended' doesn't seem to get fired when its pressed?

Comment: No idea about that, I haven't really used the video element much myself. Perhaps "seeking" or "seeked"?

Answer (score 14):

Subscribe to all `<video>` or `<audio>` events at once:

```js
function addListenerMulti(el, s, fn) {
    s.split(' ').forEach(e => el.addEventListener(e, fn, false));
}

var video = document.getElementById('myVideo');

addListenerMulti(video, 'abort canplay canplaythrough durationchange emptied encrypted ended error interruptbegin interruptend loadeddata loadedmetadata loadstart mozaudioavailable pause play playing progress ratechange seeked seeking stalled suspend timeupdate volumechange waiting', function(e){
    console.log(e.type);
});
```

It's also a good idea to study media events list from [the specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events).

Multiple events listener credits go to [@RobG's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796988/binding-multiple-events-to-a-listener-without-jquery).

Comment: This helped me immensely - thank you.  I used it to create the following question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786361/html5-video-with-autoplay-block-source-folder-from-being-renamed