# Can I combine event listeners with the same target element?

Tags: javascript, events

... and callback method?

```
input_element.addEventListener("paste", self.hide, false);
input_element.addEventListener("keypress", self.hide, false);
input_element.addEventListener("drop", self.hide, false);
```

to a form similar to this -

```
input_element.addEventListener("paste keypress drop", self.hide, false);
```

I checked [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) and the API does not support this form but is there perhaps another way?

Comment: Store the function once in a variable before binding the events, then pass a reference to it to all the `addEventListener` calls. That doesn't accomplish you wanting to pass multiple event types to one `addEventListener` call, but it removes the need for multiple anonymous functions doing the same thing

Comment: It's possible to accomplish this using jQuery, incase you're interested in introducing libraries.

Comment: No you can't, it's that simple. You can however pass a named function.

Comment: Write your own function, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8797106/961695

Comment: @adeno - are you saying the form I provided will work?

Comment: No, I'm saying you can't pass more than one event at the time, but you can use the same function for all of them, but you still have to call addEventListener for each event.

Comment: You can of course create all sorts  of convience functions, like this one -> **http://jsfiddle.net/7HBnh/**

Comment: @Yuriy - yep, I like splitting on the space character wrather than white space like Backbone does with its custom events.

Comment: @adeno - The link Yuriy provided has a better form, but both will work.  What is the jQuery solution?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/ is the jQuery solution

Answer (score 4):

Few years later, I don't see what's the difference between the example in the question and what I've written, so here is an update

```
["paste", "keypress", "drop"].forEach(event => input_element.addEventListener(event, self.hide, false));
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

First thing that came to mind

```
function hide(){
    self.hide();
}

input_element.addEventListener("paste", hide, false);
input_element.addEventListener("keypress", hide, false);
input_element.addEventListener("drop", hide, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

The obvious DRY point is to declare the function once:

```
var updateFn = function () {
    self.hide()
};
input_element.addEventListener("paste", updateFn, false);
input_element.addEventListener("keypress", updateFn, false);
input_element.addEventListener("drop", updateFn, false);
```

There *are* other ways of doing it, but they probably aren't very sensible for you.