# Javascript equivalent to $.on

Tags: javascript, jquery

As somebody who (**unfortunately**) learned more of `jQuery` than *raw* `javascript` I am just now taking the time to replace all of my code with raw `javascript`. No, it's not needed, but it's an easier way for me to learn. A problem I am facing is converting all of my `$(document).on` with raw `javascript`. My website is a "single-page application" and most of my actual `HTML` is in different files which are called via `Ajax` requests. So, my question is, how would I look for an `event` fired from dynamically loaded content? I am assuming I would have to add an `onclick` event to them, but how is it that `jQuery` does it without needing an `onclick` `event`?

Comment: Do you want to know how AJAX callbacks work? Or just any JavaScript event callback?

Comment: All I want to know is how I can load dynamic content e.g. `<div id="loadedContent">Loaded</div>` and then listen for when the user clicks on that element without adding an `onclick` attribute.

Comment: Knowing how to do things in raw JS is valuable, but the things you can do with `$.on` are truly fantastic, `jQuery`'s eventing system is architected very well. Don't try and replace it with raw JS, it's too much effort. Read through the `jQuery` source if you want to know how it works, but don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I suggest using a framework, such as backbone.js, Backbone has built in event delegation.

Comment: And what browsers should that work in? What type of selectors, jQuery has a complete selector engine built in? What kind of events, not all events bubbles, jQuery fixes that. Event delegation in itself is rather simple, you attach the event to an element that exists and checks the events target, but there's a lot of things that jQuery has that makes event delegation easier.

Comment: event delegation to the root element

Comment: @Josh: Don't let people tell you it's too much work or not worth it. I started off with jQuery just like you but then broke away and learned the native DOM. Haven't looked back. Totally worth it. I build a micro library that I use. My code is as succinct as jQuery (or more at times), is much faster, and the library is only a few KB gzipped. People told me *"don't reinvent the wheel"*. So glad I ignored them.

Comment: I recommend to read http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html to learn more about event handling.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Binding handlers in native API is done using `addEventListener()`.

To emulate jQuery's event delegation, you could fairly easily create a system that uses the `.matches()` method to test the selector you give.

```
function delegate(el, evt, sel, handler) {
    el.addEventListener(evt, function(event) {
        var t = event.target;
        while (t && t !== this) {
            if (t.matches(sel)) {
                handler.call(t, event);
            }
            t = t.parentNode;
        }
    });
}
```

There are probably some tweaks to be made, but basically it's a function that takes the element to bind to, like `document`, the event type, a selector and the handler.

It starts on the `e.target` and traverses up the parents until it gets to the bound element. Each time, it checks to see if the current element matches the selector, and if so, it invokes the handler.

So you'd call it like this:

```
delegate(document, "click", ".some_elem", function(event) {
    this.style.border = "2px dashed orange";
});
```

---

Here's a live demo that also adds dynamic elements to show that new elements are picked up as well.

```js
function delegate(el, evt, sel, handler) {
    el.addEventListener(evt, function(event) {
        var t = event.target;
        while (t && t !== this) {
            if (t.matches(sel)) {
                handler.call(t, event);
            }
            t = t.parentNode;
        }
    });
}

delegate(document, "click", ".some_elem", function(event) {
    this.parentNode.appendChild(this.cloneNode(true));
    this.style.border = "2px dashed orange";
});
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="some_elem">
    <span>
      CLICK ME
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

---

Here's a shim to add a bit more support for `.matches()`.

```
if (!Element.prototype.matches) {
  Element.prototype.matches = 
    Element.prototype.matchesSelector || 
    Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector ||
    Element.prototype.mozMatchesSelector ||
    Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector || 
    Element.prototype.oMatchesSelector || 
    function(s) {
        var matches = (this.document || this.ownerDocument).querySelectorAll(s),
            i = matches.length;
        while (--i >= 0 && matches.item(i) !== this) {}
        return i > -1;            
    };
}
```

Comment: If only `matches()` was widely supported, that would be great. Today it hardly works in any browser without a prefix, I think it's only supported in Chrome 34 and the latest Firefox.

Comment: @adeneo: True, though you get pretty wide support, IE9+, with a simple shim. I'll add it. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Yes, there's a simple polyfill using `querySelectorAll`

Comment: Yeah, that'll pick up IE8 as well.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a javascript *equivalent* to `on()`

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on('click', '#my-id', callback);

function callback(){
   ...handler code here
}
```

**Javascript**

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target.id == 'my-id') {
      callback();
    }
});
function callback(){
   ...handler code here
}
```

With this approach, the idea is to make use of [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target). Of course, as the selector changes, your code will have to get more involved

Comment: `DOM0` syntax prevents you from adding multiple click handlers in multiple places.

Comment: @Adam, are you talking about the difference between `onclick` and `addEventListener`?

Comment: Yeah you shouldn't be using old onclick events you should be using event listeners wow -_-

Comment: How do we 'listen' to multiple events ?
$('#id1,#id2,#id3').on("click mousedown mouseup", function(e)
{
});

Comment: document.addEventListener('click mousedown mouseup', function(event)
{
    alert("Event : " + event);
    alert("ID : " + event.target.id);    
});

doesn't work

Comment: @anjanesh check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796988/binding-multiple-events-to-a-listener-without-jquery and http://jsfiddle.net/y3n1hge6/24/

Answer (score 8):

In modern browsers, you can use [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to simplify replication of jQuery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method as well as ensure that you capture event bubbling from children of the targeted element (a nuance that some other implementations overlook). Older browsers, including IE, would require a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest#Polyfill) for this to work.

```js
const on = (element, type, selector, handler) => {
  element.addEventListener(type, (event) => {
    if (event.target.closest(selector)) {
      handler(event);
    }
  });
};

on(document, 'click', '#test', (event) => console.log('click'));
```

```html
<button id="test">
  Clickable
  <i>Also Clickable</i>
</button>
```

Comment: What is "handler" here?

Comment: @Toniq - "handler" is the event handling function

Answer (score 1):

Another approach for modern browsers would be something like this:

```js
const on = (selector, event, handler, element=document) => {
  element.addEventListener(event, (e) => { if(e.target.matches(selector)) handler(e); });
};
// click will work for each selector
on('[type="button"], .test, #test','click',  e => {
  alert(e.target.innerHTML);
});
// click event will work for nested .test3 element only
on('.test3','click',  e => {
  alert(e.target.innerHTML);
},document.querySelector('.test2'));
```

```html
<div id="test">
test
</div>

<div class="test">
test 1
</div>
<div class="test">
test 2
</div>

<button type="button">
go
</button>

<div class="test3">
test 3 outer
</div>


<div class="test2">
<div class="test3">
test 3 inner
</div>
test 2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would offer a very small improvement over the [fantastic accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30880807/318467):

```
function add_event(el, name, callback, selector) {
    if (selector === undefined) {
        el.addEventListener(name, callback);
    }
    else {
        el.addEventListener(name, function(event) {
            var t = event.target;
            while (t && t !== this) {
                if (t.matches(selector)) {
                    callback.call(t, event);
                }
                t = t.parentNode;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

By switching the last 2 parameters around, you can recover the default addEventListener behavior when you leave out the selector.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add and suggest a simple jQuery like on method:
It's similar to @benvc answer with an improvement which is binding the handler to `this` pointing to the attached element.
The solution uses `Element.closest` which is widely supported. If you want to support older browsers you can add a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest#polyfill)

```
//The on() function:
const on = (ele, type, selector, handler) => {
    ele.addEventListener(type, (event) => {
        let el = event.target.closest(selector);
        if (el) handler.call(el, event); //The element is bind to this
    });
};


//Example:
on(document, 'click', '.any-selector', function(event) {
     console.log(this, event.target);
     // this         -> The .any-selector element.
     // event.target -> The firing element a descendent of any-selector
});
```