# How can I detect when an image was loaded (or failed) without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i recreate the following code in pure JavaScript?

```
$('#img').on('load error', function() { something(); });
```

Comment: What you are looking for is Custom Events in Javascript. This website explains that in detail: [Creating and triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried? Showing your attempts and efforts is important here, this isn't a free code conversion site. If you have code that isn't working as expected however, post that and you will get lots of help. See [ask]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding multiple events to a listener (without JQuery)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796988/binding-multiple-events-to-a-listener-without-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<img id="image" src="image.gif" onerror="myFunction()">
```

Or inline:

```
document.getElementById("image").addEventListener("error", function(){ something(); });
document.getElementById("image").src = filename;
```

Or from scratch:

```
var img=new Image();
img.onload=function(e) { somethingGood(); };
img.onerror=function(e) { somethingBad(); };
img.src=URL;
```