# jQuery on to native JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ho would I go about writing the following function in native Javascript?

```
this.pwdInput.on("keyup change onpaste", function() {
  let pwdInputVal = $(this).val();

  self.createTests(pwdInputVal);
})
```

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#on

Comment: I think you need this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796988/binding-multiple-events-to-a-listener-without-jquery

Comment: Another usefull link: http://codeblog.cz/vanilla/#prerequisities

Comment: Cheers guys both very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try somethind like:

```
document.getElementById('pwdInput').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
 let pwdInputVal = e.target.value;
  // ...
});
```

Here I've created handler for `change` event, you need to do the same for the rest events.