# How can I make Mousedown/Mouseup trigger on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm [creating a website](https://crscillitoe.github.io/AngularBridges/) for my friends to allow them to play a higher quality online implementation of [Hashiwokakero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashiwokakero).

Some of them have tablets, and everything on the website loads perfectly fine, but when they go to touch and drag to form a bridge from one island to another, the webpage tries to scroll instead (even though there is no scrollable area!).

Currently I am detecting mouse events using the following:

```
this.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', 
    (mouseEvent) => this.mousePressed(mouseEvent), false);

this.canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', 
    (mouseEvent) => this.mouseReleased(mouseEvent), false);
```

Is there a simple way I can go about having my mousePressed() and mouseReleased() functions invoked on mobile?

Thanks!

Comment: Try using `touchstart` and `touchend` for mobile devices.  Mobile devices don't trigger mouse events for touch events.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Similar events for touch screens will be [`touchstart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/touchstart_event) and [`touchend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/touchend_event), they are totally the same as `mousedown` and `mouseup` events for desktop. From docs:

> The `touchstart` event is fired when one or more touch points are placed
> on the touch surface.

and

> The `touchend` event is fired when one or more touch points are removed
> from the touch surface.

You can check [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent) for more info about touch events.

I also guess that **may be** you will also need to stop some events from bubbling, and if so, you can take a look at [events bubbling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/bubbles) and [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to prevent them from bubbling.

If the logic should be the same for both `mousedown`/`touchstart` and `mouseup`/`touchend` events, you can bind multiple events to the listener as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796988/binding-multiple-events-to-a-listener-without-jquery).

Comment: I didn't know about these events or the terms, so your explanation and links helped tremendously! Thanks!