# How do I add multiple event listeners to a button?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to add multiple listeners to my buttons using JavaScript ES6.
I am following [this guide](https://www.csslab.cl/2016/08/22/multiples-event-listeners-en-javascript/comment-page-1)

For some reason, it is not working for me.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Button">
```

JavaScript:

```
function multipleEventsListeners(elem, events, func) {
    events.split().forEach(e => elem.addEventListener(e, func, false));
}

const INPUT = document.querySelector('input');
multipleEventsListeners(INPUT, 'onclick ontouchstart', function(e) {
    console.log(this.tagName);
});
```

Comment: this question was already posted here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796988/binding-multiple-events-to-a-listener-without-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `split` should be `split(' ')` to split on the space

2) Your events should be `click` and `touchstart`.

```js
function multipleEventsListeners(elem, events, func) {
  events.split(' ').forEach(e => elem.addEventListener(e, func, false));
}

const INPUT = document.querySelector('input');
multipleEventsListeners(INPUT, 'click touchstart', function(e) {
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Button">
```

Comment: Thank you!! It was just what I needed!

Comment: woops deleted my answer since you covered it :) +1

Answer (score 1):

`events` is passed in as a single string - I think the problem you are having is caused by not splitting this string correctly. Use `' '` as your split separator.

```
function multipleEventsListeners(elem, events, func) {
    events.split(' ').forEach(e => elem.addEventListener(e, func, false));
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! It was just what I needed!